# temporarily short/turn off 845 motherboard

Tags: motherboard, jumper

HI,
i was wondering if there is a temporary way, to turn off the my GA-81845GV motherboard, so that pressing the power button makes it appear that the MB is faulty. is there a jumper setting to do so?
thanks!

Comment: for what purpose ?

Comment: i mean, wouldn't it just be easier to disconnect the power button if you're trying to trick somebody into believing it ? i seriously doubt mb manufacturers are putting "faulty mb simulation" jumpers on board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leave the CLR CMOS header (if there is one) in the CLR CMOS mode. Some motherboards won't come up when their VBAT is shorted to GND and it doesn't potentially do any damage to the motherboard other than clear the BIOS settings.

Answer (score 0):

Put the jumpers on backwards

Comment: so that the metallic contact strip doesnt touch the pins?

Comment: swap sides. You could also flick the voltage switch on the back of your PSU (not the off button). The higher setting usually will still make the PSU seem like its working, but the screen will get no response.

Comment: See here: http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf-JAVA/Doc/images/c00517964.jpg

Comment: cant do that either.. im doin it to fool my brother, so that i can get a new one! thats better, and faster!

Comment: This is your brother. You're a noob. j/k

Answer (score 0):

- Unplug the memory sticks -- this will cause the BIOS beeps

  - If you think that will be a giveaway,

    - also unplug the default speaker

Comment: that wont do. i cant fool my brother so easily. thats why i need some jumper switch!!

Comment: Hmmm, if your brother cannot be fooled with unplugged memory and missing speaker beeps, what you want is probably to make the machine disappear :-)

Comment: haah!! thats funny :)